# What is the difference between Yajna and Havana?

Tags: yajna, vedic-rituals

While reading Rigveda, I often encounter these two closely related words, so often that the entire scripture seems to depend on these two words only. The problem is that I can't point out the actual difference between them. While Havana is perhaps some kind of burnt sacrifice given to Devatas, certainly performed by humans, Yajna seems to be a deed of the Devatas (divine beings personifying the forces of nature) themselves. Another implication is that Yajna is something happening between the humans and the divine beings(but I am pretty sure that it is not the same as Havana).

My study suggests me that Yajna is a kind of directive measure taken in order to channelize the extremely random forces of nature by manipulating their consciousness.

Comment: Yajna/Homa/Havana basically mean the same thing and that is fire sacrifice. Yajna have more wide usages though where Homa/Havana are never used. For e.g. we have the concepts of Antar/Bahir Yajna (outer/inner worship) but we never say something like say Antar Homa etc.,

Comment: @Rickross, I disagree with your point , for literally Yajna  is not only a fire sacrifice but ANY kind of devotional sacrifice made to the superior beings, whereas Havan specifically refers to the fire sacrifices done for invocatinal purposes.

Comment: Yes tht I know and I hv also mentioned it in the comment. Yajna hv wider usages than Homa/Havana.

Comment: @Rickross, Hmmm..., now I see your point. It would be a great help if you can provide me some sources from the vedic literature explicitly describing the meaning and purpose of Yajna , so that I can get the broader concept required for the continuation of my studies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Havana:

Havana means the act of offering oblations in fire. Homa has exactly the same meaning.

From [Sanskrit Dictionary](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=havana&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3), few meanings of Havana are as follows:

> हवन   n.  havana      invocation  
>      हवन    m.  havana      god of fire 
>      हवन    m.
>     havana      fire-receptacle 
>      हवन    n.  havana      summons 
>      हवन    n.
>     havana      sacrifice   
>      हवन    n.  havana      challenging or challenge to
>   battle    
>      हवन    n.  havana      act of offering an oblation with fire

Right now I am not able to find a reference where the word Havana is found. But, for Homa I can give a reference:

> sandhyA snAnam japo **homo** devatAtithipujanam |
>  Atithyam
>   vaiswadevam cha shatkarmAni dine dine ||
>
> Ablution and prayer, inaudible recitation (of sacred words), **burnt-
>   offerings**, the worship of gods, hospitality to guests unexpectedly
>   come, and offerings made in the name of the Visvadevam, — these are
>   the six duties to be performed every day
>
> *ParAshara Smriti 1.39*

### Yajna:

Yajna also has a similar meaning but it can imply more things besides fire sacrifices. It can mean sacrifice, offering etc.

Few meanings of [Yajna](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=yajJa&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) are:

> Sacrifice, act of worship or devotion, prayer, fire, worship,
>   offering.

So, while Havana/Homa has to be an offering made unto fire, **Yajna is not necessarily the same**. For example Japa Yajna - the act of doing Mantra Japa, here fire is not involved but still it's a Yajna.

Here is one such use of Yajna in scriptures where it is not referring to a sacrifice involving fire:

> Iswara Uvacha:
>
> **Japa Yajnath Paro Yajno** NAparohastiha Kaschana ||
>  Tasmajjapen
>   DharmArthaKAmaMokshanscha SAdhayeth ||
>
> There is no Yajna which is superior to Japa Yajna, hence one should
>   attain Dharma, Artha, Kama & Moksha through Japa.
>
> *KulArnava Tantram,Chapter 15,Verse 3.*

Some further references of how the word Yajna is used in Vedas are as follows:

> Yat purushena havishA (1) deva yajnam atanvata (2) vasanto asyasid
>   Ajyam (3) grishma idhmah sharad havih (4) ||
>
> With Purusha as the offering (1) the devas performed a sacrifice (2);
>   spring was the Ajya (3), summer the fuel (samit), and autumn (sharat)
>   the offering (4).
>
> *RigVeda 10.90.6*

Now, here Yajna may not be a fire sacrifice, because fire or Agni was said to be born (in one of the subsequent Mantras) as a result of this sacrifice.

Yet another Mantra which uses the word Yajna in it. The meaning of this Mantra is quite difficult to comprehend in my opinion.

> Yajnena yajnam ayajanta devAh (1) tAni dharmAni prathamAni Asan (2) te
>   ha nakam mahimAnah sachanta (3) yatra purve sAdhyAh santi devAh (4) ||
>
> By sacrifice Gods sacrificed to sacrifice (1). These were the earliest
>   established principles (Dharma) (2). The Mighty Ones in this way
>   reached perfect bliss (3), Where dwell the Gods, ancients, who made
>   the Way straight (4).
>
> *Rigveda 10.90.16*